# Nuxt 3 middleware from and to routes are always the same

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

I am facing a strange problem in my Nuxt 3 application. I do want to add my first middleware to my project called `auth.ts`. This middleware should protect certain pages from users who are not logged in. Basically it should grant access to the requested page to those who are logged in and navigate those who are not logged in to the login page. Quite simple and straight forward.

However, my `to` and `from` variables in my middleware are always the same. This results in an `infinite redirection in a navigation guard`.

This is my middleware:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    const userStore = useUserStore();

    console.log('From auth middleware')
    console.log('to', to)
    console.log('from', from)
    console.log('authenticated', userStore.authenticated)

    // If the user is authenticated, continue to the requested route
    if (userStore.authenticated === true) {
        return navigateTo(to.fullPath);
    }

    // If the user is not authenticated, redirect to the login page
        return navigateTo('/login');
    })
```

The `authenticated` variable comes from my Pinia store.

This is how I add the middleware to my `/profile` page:

```
definePageMeta({ middleware: ["auth"] });
```

This is the error I get:

```
[Vue Router warn]: Detected a possibly infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/profile" to "/profile". Aborting to avoid a Stack Overflow. Are you always returning a new location within a navigation guard? That would lead to this error. Only return when redirecting or aborting, that should fix this. This might break in production if not fixed.
```

This is the console log I get from my `auth.ts` middleware:

```
From auth middleware auth.ts:4:9

to Object { fullPath: "/profile", hash: "", query: {}, name: "profile", path: "/profile", params: {}, matched: (1) […], meta: Proxy, redirectedFrom: {…}, href: "/profile" } auth.ts:5:9

from Object { fullPath: "/profile ", path: "/profile", query: {}, hash: "", name: "profile", params: {}, matched: (1) […], meta: {…}, redirectedFrom: undefined, href: "/profile " } auth.ts:6:9

authenticated true
```

When the user is not authenticated it successfully navigates the user to the `/login` page. But when the user is logged in I always get the error. It would make sense to me if I am already on the profile page and then refresh the page.

But I get this error as well when I am at `/` and navigate to the `/profile` page. But how can the `from` variable be `/profile` when I navigate from the `/` page to the `/profile` page?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply because when it's authenticated, instead of continuing the middleware, you redirect to a new instance of current route which will **run a new middleware**. To fix it, you should return nothing:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  const userStore = useUserStore();

  console.log("From auth middleware");
  console.log("to", to);
  console.log("from", from);
  console.log("authenticated", userStore.authenticated);

  // If the user is authenticated, continue to the requested route
  if (userStore.authenticated === true) {
    return // returns nothing means continue the middleware, instead of redirect again
  }

  // If the user is not authenticated, redirect to the login page
  return navigateTo("/login");
});
```

From the [official docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware#usage):

> Possible return values are:
>
> - nothing (a simple return or no return at all) - does not block navigation and will move to the next middleware function, if any, or complete the route navigation

Comment: You are correct! But I still get the same `to` and `from` path. How can this be? Isn't `from` the path where the user comes from and `to` to which path he wants to go? They are always the same when I print them...

Comment: @Jan hmm that's odd, how did you move from one page to another? Do you use `nuxt-link` or `router.push`? You should use them I guess

Comment: I just type it into my URL